# Use "With" with Tensorflow Sessions

Tags: python, tensorflow

The tutorial says in order to release resources after computation is complete, I can use `with tf.Session() as sess` as the scope, and the session will be closed after the scope.

However, if I want to make predictions and do some further computations with the model trained in this session, I am not able to do it because the session is closed after the training. What shall I do? Shall I use `sess = tf.Session()` at the beginning and `sess.close()` after I finish my job with this model? If so, what is the point of using `with` statement which does not allow me doing anything after the training?

Comment: ... put the stuff you want to do inside the `with` statement too?

Comment: use the same session for training and predicting. Or save the model and load it in a prediction only loop.

Comment: I don't really like using `with` blocks either, you can just do `sess = tf.Session()`. `close` will be called automatically in `__del__` when the session is garbage collected

Comment: Thanks guy. What is the information stored in the session object?